# Prove that a number is integer...

Tags: number-theory, integers

We have the following exercise: "Let $q\in\mathbb C$ and $f:\mathbb N \to \mathbb C$ an arithmetic function such that $$(\star )\space q^n =\sum_{d\mid n}df(d)$$(i) Find the value $f(24)$ and (ii) Prove that, if $q\in \mathbb Z$
 then,  $f(24)\in\mathbb Z$"

For (i): We apply Mobius's Inverse Formula on $(\star)$ and we have:$$nf(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}q^dμ \left ( \frac{n}{d} \right )$$ where μ is the Mobius function. So,$$24f(24)=\sum_{d\mid n}q^dμ\left ( \frac{24}{d} \right )=q^4-q^8-q^{12}+q^{24} \implies f(24)=\frac{q^4-q^8-q^{12}+q^{24}}{24} $$ For (ii): I made some attempts but only with intuition.

Any help\advise\hint would be very helpful. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use `$n\mid m$` for $n\mid m$.

Comment: Isn't it a direct corollary of the inversion formula? Substituting $n=q$ and dividing through by $q$, you get
  $$ f(q) = \sum_{d\mid q} q^{d-1}\mu(q/d) $$
which, obviously, is an integer.

Comment: Note that in your final result for $f(24)$ there is an error in the sign of $q^{24}$.

Comment: Let $f_q(n)$ denote $f(n)$ for a particular value of $q$.  If $q$ is a positive integer, then combinatorially, $f_q(n)$ is the number of ways to form a necklace of using $n$  beads each having one of $q$ possible colors in an asymmetric manner,  that is, the only rotations that leave the necklace invariant are full rotations.  (Reflections do not count here.)   From this, we can conclude that $f_q(n)$ is an integer for all integers $q$ (since $f_{q+n}(n)\equiv f_q(n)\pmod{1}$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $q$ is odd then $q^2\equiv 1 \mod 8$. Then $$q^4-q^8-q^{12}+q^{24}\equiv 1-1-1+1\equiv0 \mod 8$$

If $q$ is even  then $q^4\equiv 0 \mod 8$. Then, again, $q^4-q^8-q^{12}+q^{24}\equiv 0 \mod 8$.

Either $q^2\equiv 1 \mod 3$ or $q\equiv 0 \mod 3$ and so $q^4-q^8-q^{12}+q^{24}\equiv 0 \mod 3$.

Therefore $q^4-q^8-q^{12}+q^{24}\equiv 0 \mod 24$, as you require.

Comment: Ohh i see..Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad to be of help.